# Cocoa Touch: How can I update the table view everytime I tap on a tab of tabbar?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uitabbar

I'm using iOS 8 and Objective c.
If I do a change in the values in one view, I can't see the reflection on my other tabviews. But if I re-run the app, I can see the reflection on the other tabs. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. How can I make sure that when I tap on a tabview, it will be reload according to the database?

Comment: You haven't provided any details about what you are doing. As it stands, this question can't be answered very well because it's too vague. Update your question with relevant code and more specific details about what you are doing, what you want to happen, and what issues you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
Here is my code:
"TheMaster" is the main tabview. Here selectedIndex can be 0,1,2.... according to the placement of the tab. The leftmost tab has the index 0, and after that 1,2, and so on.

```
   UITabBarController *controller = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TheMaster"];
    controller.selectedIndex=0;
            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying in your code, but you can try to implement the viewDidAppear method with a reloadData in your tableView:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[tableView reloadData]` is the one you are looking for , this UITableView method refreshes the table view by calling its delegate and data source methods again to get fresh data.